# Opencart 3. Add new Field in oc_ product_image

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I'm newbie, and trying to figure it out myself, but now I'm at a dead end.

It is need to add a description field for additional product images in the "image" tab.

What I've done. In admin\model\catalog\product.php line 76 and 222 insert:

```
if (isset($data['product_image'])) {
        foreach ($data['product_image'] as $product_image) {

                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', image = '" . $this->db->escape($product_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$product_image['sort_order'] . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', img_description = '" .  $this->db->escape($product_image['img_description']) . "'");

        }
    }
```

In admin\controller\catalog\product.php line 1079 insert:

```
$data['product_images'][] = array(
        'image' => $image,
        'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($thumb, 100, 100),
        'sort_order' => $product_image['sort_order'],
        'img_description' => $product_image['img_description']
     );
```

In admin\view\template\catalog\product_form.twig inserted fields with language bindings (there are two languages on the site)

```
<td class="text-right">{% for language in languages %}
                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><img src="language/{{ language.code }}/{{ language.code }}.png" title="{{ language.name }}" /></span>
                    <textarea name="product_image[{{ image_row }}][{{ language.language_id }}][img_description]" rows="5" placeholder="{{ entry_img_description }}" class="form-control">{{ product_image[language.language_id] ? product_image[language.language_id].img_description }}</textarea>
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
                </td>
```

In the database in the table oc_product_image I added the fields `img_description` and `language_id` (the id of the language added to PRIMARY and attribute is "primary" - I use OpenServer).

After saving the changes, I updated the modifiers in the tab.

I did not move to the part of the field output, because got errors when updating product card:

> Notice: Undefined index: img_description in **\system\storage\modification\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 250Notice: Undefined index: img_description in **\system\storage\modification\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 250Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at **\admin\controller\startup\error.php:34) in **\system\library\response.php on line 36

I checked this file, in the specified place (line 250) there is nothing, and in the places related to `product_image` the corresponding changes are made as described above.

Kind people, help solve the problem please.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you add new field `img_description` to you DB?

Comment: Yes. I add in oc_product_image tab new field img_description

Comment: OK, if you look at your code so you can see that there are two different arrays `$data['product_images']` in controller and `$data['product_image']` in model.

Comment: it create massive $data['product_images'][] from $data['product_image']. Like this foreach ($product_images as $product_image)

Comment: seems like problem in frontend. For some reason your new field don't get in POST. Can you check that? Print POST array that you get in model after submit.